# error when using pagination in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, pagedlist

I use this post for pagination table in asp.net mvc

> http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

But I have an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable 2[KaspianCms.Models.News,System.DateTime]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList 1[KaspianCms.Models.News]'.

My controller code:

```
    public ViewResult Index(int? page)
    {
        int pageSize = 3;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        var news = from s in db.News
                   select s;
        return View(news.ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
    }
```

and my view:

```
@using KaspianCms.Models;
@model PagedList.IPagedList<KaspianCms.Models.News>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
```

Comment: can you show your `ToPagedList` difinition? Or signature?

Comment: what definition? I'm using `PagedList.Mvc`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
    var news = from s in db.News
               select s;
    return View(news.ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
```

To

```
  var news = db.News
  ViewData.Model = news.ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize);
  return View();
```

Not sure if it helps. Also your is `db.News` table of `KaspianCms.Models.News`?